# Share setting files between applications in .net

Tags: .net, application-settings

I have an application where I store the connection string into a configuration file (it's in the my.settings for now but that could change if needed). When I want to change the connection string, I get an error saying I do not have the privilege. I have to "Run as administrator" to be able to change the file.

What I was thinking was to create another simple application (console application most likely) that would change those setting. This application would require the Administration privileges via the UAC (I use a manifest file and it seems to work so far). Problem is, I can't seem to find a way to read the my.settings files from the other application.

The application will sit in the same folder as the main app. Is there a way that both application share the same "My.Settings" or is there a way to create a share setting files ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of trying to hack together a solution to edit the settings file in the ProgramFiles folder just store the settings in the `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "yourAppName")` folder.

Comment: I though setting files where only stored in the program files folder.. I'll have to look into that.